# "TTY mode requires /dev/tty to be read/writable."

Tags: php, ubuntu, docker-compose, sudo, laravel-9

When I run this code in Laravel v9.0,

> ```
> $process = new Process(['sudo','docker','login','-u',$this->git_username,'-p',$this->git_token,$this->docker_image_url]);
> $process->setTty(true);
> $process->run();`
> ```

I keep to get this error
`"TTY mode requires /dev/tty to be read/writable."`

While refer laravel documentation, I notice this process is available at version 10. but if I remove `$process->setTty(true);`, it run well. but I need to run with sudo because need root permission.

please help me, thanks in advance.

when I run without `sudo` and `$process->setTty(true);` in Process
this is the result

```
WARNING! Using --password via the CLI is insecure. Use --password-stdin. permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Post "http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.24/auth": dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied
```

and when I run without only `$process->setTty(true);` in Process
this is the result

```
sudo: a terminal is required to read the password; either use the -S option to read from standard input or configure an askpass helper sudo: a password is required
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issues.
I don't think tty mode is possible programmatically. I use shell_exec function instead and it worked well for me.

So for instance,

```
$process = shell_exec ('sudo docker login -u '.$this->git_username.' -p '.$this->git_token.' '.$this->docker_image_url]);
```

Comment: Hi Dustin, Thank you for your suggestion! it helped for me, but I can't track the logs for the command when output the process variable.

Comment: You may add " 2>&1" at the end of the command.

Answer (score 0):

**Fixing the /dev/tty Read/Write Issue**

If you are experiencing the /dev/tty read/write issue, there are a few steps you can take to try and resolve it. The first thing to check is whether or not you have the necessary permissions to access the file. You can do this by running the following command:

```
ls -l /dev/tty
```

This will show you the permissions for the /dev/tty file. If the permissions are set to something other than read/write for the user, you may need to adjust them using the chmod command. For example, you could run the following command to give the user read/write permissions:

```
sudo chmod u+rw /dev/tty
```

If the permissions are already set correctly, the issue may be due to the file being locked by another process. You can check for this by running the following command:

```
sudo lsof /dev/tty
```

This will show you a list of processes that are currently using the /dev/tty file. If you see any processes listed, you may need to terminate them in order to free up the file. You can do this by running the following command:

```
sudo kill
```

Replace with the process ID of the process you want to terminate.

Reference: https://devcodef1.com/news/1001359/tty-mode-and-dev-tty-read-write-issue